# installing mingw libpython error on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, theano

I am getting missing package error on Mac OSX. I am using Python 3.6.1 and Anaconda 4.4.0
I am trying to install g++ for theano using following command 
**conda install mingw libpython**

I am getting following output:
**PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
  - mingw**

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why'd you want MinGW on Mac? Why'd you try to install g++ in such a complicated way? Just install XCode and its command-line tools, which include clang++, the C++ compiler.

Comment: I already have installed xcode, so I don't have to worry about it, right? I'm actually new to it and was following a video tutorial for implementing CNN. Thank you

Comment: then, you should install XCode command-line tools. There's a section about this in the XCode settings.